# How do I connect to a MySQL database server running on PlanetScale with SSL from node.js on localhost?

Tags: mysql, node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, planetscale

I'm trying to connect to the MySQL server on PlanetScale, but can't as it requires SSL.

Here's their doc for that, but it's unclear what it says.
https://planetscale.com/docs/concepts/secure-connections

Here's the connection URL: `DATABASE_URL='mysql://co30rXXXXXXX:pscale_pw_XXXXXXX@hoqx01444p30.us-east-4.psdb.cloud/restaurant?ssl={"rejectUnauthorized":true}'`

Here's what I see from my terminal when I run `yarn run migration-run`

> yarn run v1.22.18 $ npx prisma migrate dev Environment variables
> loaded from .env Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
> Datasource "db": MySQL database "restaurant" at
> "hoqx0XXXXX.us-east-4.psdb.cloud:3306"
>
> Error: Migration engine error: unknown error: Code: UNAVAILABLE server
> does not allow insecure connections, client must use SSL/TLS
>
> error Command failed with exit code 1. info Visit
> https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this
> command.

Is there anyone who has tried to connect to PlanetScale DB from Node.js on localhost? I have tried some other suggestions from Stackoverflow, but don't seem to work.

Comment: PS: 
`ssl={"rejectUnauthorized":false}`
I tried this option as well from other answers, but doesn't work.

Comment: You probably need [`sslcert=<PATH>`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mysql#configuring-an-ssl-connection) to [set the path to the root certificate](https://planetscale.com/docs/concepts/secure-connections#ca-root-configuration).

Comment: @RickN Thank you for your advice! Sorry for the late reply, but I have managed to do it already! :) SSL cert path fixed the problem. So I have added `?ssl={"rejectUnauthorized":false}&sslcert=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

Comment: @DreamBig Thanks it works but one more error occured after this, Error: P1001

Can't reach database server at `ap-northeast.connect.psdb.cloud`:`3306`

Please make sure your database server is running at `ap-northeast.connect.psdb.cloud`:`3306`.    /// it is completely fine when I run on localhost, only the problem when it is on the Cloud (GCP)

Comment: @nounlace Replacing /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt with /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt for local environment solved the issue. The solution for me at this point would be having four different URLs at environment variables list (two with /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt for local and two with /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt for preview and prod).  You can read more here: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/8875 Hope it helps!

Comment: hi @dreambold how did you create the ssl cert for the planetscale database?? and did you have any further errors afterwards??

Comment: @Jriffs Where is your domain hosted?

Comment: @dreambold my app from which I'm trying to connect to the planetscale database is hosted on Heroku, and i was given a domain by them.

Comment: Does the app have a domain with SSL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`?ssl={"rejectUnauthorized":false}&sslcert=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

Adding these params at the end of the connection link, the issue has been fixed. :)

Comment: can someone please help me with how to create the ssl cert ?

Comment: you can use `letsencrypt` https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/ or you can issue one from your domain registrar

Comment: https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=apache&os=ubuntufocal For `Ubuntu` running Apache server,

Answer (score 1):

#### SSL ISSUE ON WINDOWS

If you're working on a Windows machine and using a `.env` file for your connection string, here is what worked for me to run locally (windows does not have a default `/etc/ssl/certs/` reference [as answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26951330/3371361)).

You get your connection string from the PlanetScale console, via "overview" > "connect"

This will look something like:

```
DATABASE_URL='mysql://xxxxxx:*****@aws-eu-west-1.connect.psdb.cloud/dbName?ssl={"rejectUnauthorized":true}'
```

When plainly using this you will most likley get the follow error message (as the question states):

```
Code: UNAVAILABLE server does not allow insecure connections, client must use SSL/TLS
```

You therefore need to provide a local cert, one can be downloaded from the following trusted location:

- https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html

Next, you need to save this file to a logical location on disk that can be referenced in your connection string, for example `c:/temp/cacert.pem`

Once saved you can then append the following to your connection string:

```
&sslcert=C:\\temp\\cacert.pem
```

Restart your server and you should be all set!

The equivelant ssl cert update in `NodeJs` would look as follows:

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'hostNameHere',
    user: 'userNameHere',
    password: 'passwordHere',
    database: 'dbHere',
    ssl: {
        ca: fs.readFileSync('C:\\temp\\cacert.pem')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
?ssl={"rejectUnauthorized":false}&sslaccept=strict
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).