# Cannot connect Planetscale DB to NextJS project (Prisma Error: P1001)

Tags: next.js, prisma, planetscale

### **Project architecture**

[image]

---

### **Background**

Trying to connect a DB to my NextJS project. Decided to use https://www.mockaroo.com/ to generate mock DB. Then used the Planetscale browser console to create the table and insert the values with the SQL generated by mockaroo.

*Successfully have a table in Planetscale*

[image]

---

### **Problem**

When doing **`npx prisma studio`**

*ERROR*

```
Message: Error in Prisma Client request: 

Invalid `prisma.mOCK_DATA.findMany()` invocation:

Can't reach database server at `us-east.connect.psdb.cloud`:`3306`

Please make sure your database server is running at `us-east.connect.psdb.cloud`:`3306`.
```

When doing **`npx prisma db pull`**

*ERROR*

```
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Environment variables loaded from .env
Datasource "db": MySQL database "MydbName" at "us-east.connect.psdb.cloud:3306"

✖ Introspecting based on datasource defined in prisma\schema.prisma

Error: P1001

Please make sure your database server is running at `us-east.connect.psdb.cloud`:`3306`.
```

---

### **scheme.prisma**

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["referentialIntegrity"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url = env("DATABASE_URL")
  referentialIntegrity = "prisma"
}
```

### **.env**

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://{username}:{password}@us-east.connect.psdb.cloud:3306/MydbName"
```

---

### **Summary**

I cannot connect to the Planetscale DB from my NextJS project without an ERROR connecting. I have researched this issue online and found people with the issue. But applying their changes did not fix anything i.e. https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5132. For instance I tried appending `?ssl_mode=require&sslcert==us-east-1-bundle.pem` to the DATABASE_URL but no changes.

I will attempt this fix soon: [How do I connect to a server with SSL from node.js on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73455318/how-do-i-connect-to-a-server-with-ssl-from-node-js-on-localhost)

Comment: How are you selecting the connection string from PlanetScale dashboard?
Are you selecting Prisma as a method or Node.js as a method while getting the connection string?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: @DreamBold No I never solved it. It worked on a different network on a different computer. I am certain it is a firewall issue on the network and not planetscale.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73455318/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-server-with-ssl-from-node-js-on-localhost Would this help?

Comment: @DreamBold I have decided to just use Microsoft Sql Server so I am no longer working with Planetscale. But thank you.